# mysql --ssl-verify-server-cert=true is returning "SSL certificate validation failure"

Tags: mysql, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

By trying to setup Mysql over SSL on RHEL6 I'm facing an error any time I ask mysql client to verify the self-signed certs :

```
mysql --ssl-ca=/tmp/newcerts/ca.pem \
 --ssl-cert=/tmp/newcerts/client-cert.pem \
 --ssl-key=/tmp/newcerts/client-key.pem \
 -h IP.IP.IP.IP -u USER -p \
 --ssl-verify-server-cert=true

ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL certificate validation failure
```

In the case where I set *--ssl-verify-server-cert=false* mysql does not verify the self-signed certs and start the secure connexion.

I've used the Mysql HowTo article to create my self-signed certificate : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html and the openssl verify command is returning :

```
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem server-cert.pem client-cert.pem

server-cert.pem: OK
client-cert.pem: OK
```

The ca.pem & client-cert.pem & server-cert.pem have been created with a different Common Name as Node1 for ca.pem, Node2 for client-cert.pem, Node3 for server-cert.pem

Param loaded into Mysql during startup :

```
ssl-ca=/tmp/newcerts/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/tmp/newcerts/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/tmp/newcerts/server-key.pem
```

Then I've added the ca.pem to the server by following those steps for RHEL6 :

```
update-ca-trust force-enable
cp /tmp/newcerts/ca.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
update-ca-trust extract
```

I'm guessing with a proper cert verified by a trusted third party I should not have this error but I need to verify that it work with a self-signed cert.

I running out of idea to get this working. Does someone already faced a similar issue?

Comment: I guess you need to add your ca.pem to your trusted root certificates, otherwise the server tries to verify that certificate up the cert chain but is unable to find a trusted cert that signs down the chain

Comment: Thanks for the response. Good idea, I'm going to give a try and post the result!

Comment: I've edit my post with the update-ca commands to add the ca.pem to the trusted root certificates of the servers but I'm still facing the issue. Do you think the new commands listed in the post are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case (and for a self-signed certificate) the solution was :

- **No need** to add ca.pem to the trusted root certificates
- **Need** to set the CN of the server-cert.pem as the mysqlserverhostname
- Make sure to resolve mysqlserverhostname from your client
- Replace `-h IP.IP.IP.IP -u USER -p` by `-h mysqlserverhostname -u USER -p`

My error was to follow the [Mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html) instructions where the quote "To generate test files, you can press Enter to all prompts" seems incorrect where **I had to set the CN of the server-cert.pem as the mysqlserverhostname** to resolve the issue.

Comment: could you please name an example for your third bullet?